# How to send selected grouped data to csv file

Tags: python, pandas

This works great for displaying to the screen:

```
gb = grouped_df.groups
gb.keys()

key_list_from_gb = [key1, key2, key3]

for key, values in gb.items():
    if key in key_list_from_gb:
        print(df.ix[values], "\n")
```

How would I direct the output to a csv file instead? Thanks!!!

Comment: Look up `with open(...)` and `fp.write()`.

Comment: Does `gb.to_csv(...` not work?

Comment: Well I tried to guess how `grouped_df` and `df` were related, and what could be `df.ix[values]`, but I really could not. With what you have given I can just say use `DataFrame.to_csv` if you have dataframes, or `csv.writerow` if you have an iterable. Of course, if you edit your question with a [mcve], I could give a more precise and relevant answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas DataFrames have a method `to_csv` for writing DataFrames to csv files.

```
for key, values in gb.items():
    if key in key_list_from_gb:
        result = df.ix[values]
        result.to_csv(f'path\to\file_{key}.csv')
```

Comment: That's it!!!! Thank  you so much! I knew this had to be easier than my approach!!!!